# Can't create RabbitMq exchange using dockerized spring boot application

Tags: docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I've dockerized the spring boot application and run as normal.using rabbitmq yaml settings create the exchange in Queue server but the problem is it didn't create exchange after dockerization the spring boot application.

Note:- Rabbitmq is installed on remote server. not in the docker container.

No any errors found in the log files.

If anyone got any idea it could be a great help.

the server log is mentioned below

```
2018-07-19 12:31:47.886  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc52646c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happen because of network range conflict (try to access different range application ). there are two way of connecting dockerized applications into RabbitMq

1. have to dockerized rabbitmq server 
   this approach use docker gateway IP range. This is bound to the Docker host
2. Run from machine ip address

   docker run --network host image_name

this approach use application port because this container not bound to the Docker host